# How to confirm correct changes of X509TrustManager Google Play warning issue?

Tags: android-security, trustmanager

I received warning message "Google Play warning: You are using an unsafe implementation of X509TrustManager". I removed problematic code and updated APK but warning still remains. It's probably because one of the libraries. Is there any change to confirm correct changes without releasing of APK?